# cryptosetup fails with correct password

Tags: boot, cryptsetup

On Friday my laptop running Ubuntu 18 did a system update.  Since then I have rebooted it and now it does not accept my password. It says `crypsetup failed, bad password or options`. I am sure the password is correct.  What can I do to get access to my computer again?

When I book up from USB and use Disks to look at the internal drives I believe it is /`dev/nvme0n1p3`.

I tried `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/nvme0n0p3` and get `"Device doesn't exist or access denied"`.

I'm not sure why the name is not sdxx but I noticed there is also an sda, sda1, sda2 and sda3. I don't know what those are but when I try the same cryptsetup on those I get the same response, access denied.

Any follow up ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I thinnk I'm actually running 19 but I'm not sure.  Sadly, it's impossible for me to check now

Comment: Boot into a live distribution from a USB stick, then try to mount one of the encrypted drives from there, *after you verified that the correct keyboard mapping is loaded*. This will allow you at least to check that the encrypted partitions are still ok.

Comment: Please clarify your release. Desktop and server releases use a *yy.mm* format for releases, *yy* being used only by snap based specialist releases (usually installed on appliances/devices which are headless without screen/keyboard).  *yy* releases also are only released on even years. There were no *snap* based releases in 2019 thus no 19 releases.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian.  I have tried to follow your advice and created a USB stick to boot from and that seemed to go well.  The keyboard seems to be my normal keyboard so that is not the problem.  I then used Disks to view the internal harddrives.  When I try and unlock one it asks for a passphrase.  I have tried both my encrypted password and password for my profile and they both fail.  Any other suggestions of what I should try?

Comment: @guiverc, I would like to get this information but I'm not sure how considering I can't login to my computer.  Any ideas how I can find this out?

Comment: Find out the device descriptor of your encrypted partition, like /dev/sdXX (in Disks under "Device"), then try `cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdXX` with the correct device number. You don't need to know a password for that. Post the results of that command in your original message.